# jquery table not displaying correctly in jquery vertical tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables, jquery-ui-tabs

I can get jquery datatables to display correctly using jquery horizontal tabs but not vertical tabs.  When I set it to vertical the datatable shows up underneath the tabs rather than beside them to the right.

I looked closely at the elements using chrome developer tools I see a hierarchy as follows:

```
<div id="homeContent">
<h2>Announcements</h2>
<form id="homeForm" class="cleanform" action="/VideoDataService/tabs/homeTab" method="post>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="header"> == $0
<div id="announcementTbl_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">...
```

I don't know why there are two div class="header" lines but if I mouse over the outer one it shows it takes up 0 vertical space so I don't think that's the problem.

If I mouse over the inner one it shows a big blue space that includes the table and extends all the way up to the top of the page.  So it appears that div is the culprit adding a lot of space above the table.

How do I get rid of all the extra space?  I've tried

```
div.header {
margin-top: -500px;
padding: 0px;
border:0px;
}
```

But it did nothing.  I also tried:

```
#homeContent {
margin-left: 230px;
margin-top: -500px;
}
```

But it also did nothing.  I also tried setting margin-top to 0 and border and padding to 0.  Also tried float:top; Nothing worked.

I also have the following settings, using https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical as a guide:

```
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical {
    width: 1500px;
} 

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-widget-header {
    background:white;
}

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
    font-size:65%;
    clear: left;
}

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
    display: block;
}

.ui-tabs-panel {
    float right;
    width:1200px;
}
```

Also tried changing display to inline and inline-block.  Nothing worked.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If I change width to 1000px in .ui-tabls-panel, then it works.  Wierd.  But then it's way off to the right of the page.  I can't figure out how to get it next to the tabs.

Comment: This should help: http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/

Comment: I got it to work using float:left in .ui-tabs-panel.  The guide was using float:right but apparently if the content is coming from a different url, not the same page, then you can use float left.